# Most accessible existence and uniqueness theorems proof?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm taking an ODEs course, and students are expected to know quite a bit about real analysis, which I haven't yet taken, and some of the proofs are quite indecipherable for me.

I could just learn the methods and probably pass the course, but  I think that would be pretty dumb, as it's not the reason why I started it.

At this moment I'm really really interested in understanding a proof for the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs, does anyone know one which doesn't require much more than what you learn in a typical Calc$1$/$2$(multivariable) course?  Thanks!

Comment: Completeness of $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ is essential to existence. Therefore, I do not think that there can be a proof which you could understand without knowing this fact. You can of course sidestep formality issues, but since the space is abstract for a bypasser, intuition is not a good helping hand and you will not feel that you are understanding things if you do so.

Comment: In an older edition of Boyce/DiPrima's **Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems** (1969, 2nd edition) there was a very nice section that gave an overview of how the existence theorem can be proved in a way that is analogous to how the intermediate value theorem can be used to locate roots of algebraic and transcendental equations.